# Cómo importar itextpdf en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, itext, itextpdf

He visto algunas soluciones de cómo se importa pero ninguna me funciona.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>gestionAlmacen</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE160</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- always needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- always needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- always needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for forms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for PDF/A -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for digital signatures -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for barcodes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for Asian fonts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- only needed for hyphenation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
            <version>${itext.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.gestionalmacen.Main</exec.mainClass>
        <itext.version>7.2.5</itext.version>
    </properties>
    <name>gestionAlmacen</name>
</project>
```

He visto en algunos lugares cómo crear un archivo .pdf pero al seguir los pasos por ejemplo el Documento me marca error, ya que debo implementar todos los métodos, ya que es una clase abstracta pero en los ejemplos que he visto no lo hacen.

Llevo poco tiempo usando Netbeans por lo que no se por qué no me deja importar el jar desde la librería o no aparecen en la pantalla los archivos y carpetas creadas.

**FicheroPDF**

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FicheroPDF {

    private static final String NOMBRE_FICHERO = "clientes.pdf";

    public boolean crearFicher(List<Cliente> listaClientes) {
        Document documento = new Document();
        try {
            // step 2:
            // we create a writer that listens to the document
            // and directs a PDF-stream to a file
            PdfWriter.getInstance(documento,new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));

            // step 3: we open the document
            documento.open();
            // step 4: we add a paragraph to the document
            documento.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            System.err.println(de.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        // step 5: we close the document
        document.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que si me las marca en gris es por que no me las esta creando bien o algo asi,no?

Comment: A menos que ya tengas el reporte hecho en itext7, te recomiendo usar librePDF(Itext no es open source). Te paso un enlace al sitio oficial y un ejemplo que funciona https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/wiki/Hello-World

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que intento hacer pero al hacerlo las líneas se marcan en rojo y según busque  tenía que hacer import de itext7 pero lo he metido en pom.xml y aún asi no me deja hacerlo. @GavilanPatagonico

Comment: Si vas a usar iText7, te faltan dependencias. Leete esto https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-itext-7-for-java

Comment: Construye el proyecto, después de agregar los modulos

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer pero me sigue marcando error al importar Document.

Comment: @Rosa  que error específicamente estás obteniendo?

Comment: Me daba un error al importar las dependencias que había puesto en el pom.xml (Todavía no se han descargado las dependencias) por lo que no me permitía ejecutar mi programa. Así que aparte de añadirlas al pom.xml tuve que hacerlo de forma manual.

Comment: Pero ahora por ejemplo al quere usar FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD se me marca en rojo y encima a aparece (cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable HELVETICA_BOLD
  location: class FontConstants

Comment: Rosa, en **FicheroPDF**, estás importando `Document` de swing. Borrá la línea de importación e importalo de itext. Igual el problema principal es que estás usando un ejemplo que es para otra versión de iText. Leete esto https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-for-java/chapter-7-creating-pdf-ua-and-pdf-a-documents

Comment: @Rosa ahora ya tienes los .jar registrados en tu proyecto, pero estás usando el import incorrecto import javax.swing.text.Document; este no eres de iTexr, debe ser: import com.itextpdf.text.Document; revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Netbeans dentro del archivo `pom.xml` de tu proyecto agregarías las dependencias, agrega los [**modulos o dependencías**](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-itext-7-for-java#InstallingiText7forJava-UsingtheCentralRepository) dentro de:

`<project> -> <dependencies> -> <dependency>` y realiza un **Build** de tu proyecto!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa la documentación:

**[Installing iText for Java](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-itext-7-for-java)**

Después de agregar las dependencias, construye tu proyecto y se descargarán los archivos .jar necesarios para usar las clases de `iText`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma ahora podrás usar las clases de `iText` en tu proyecto.

---

Actualización:

**Al realizar los cambios descritos anteriormente, ahora tienes los .jar registrados en tu proyecto, pero ahora tienes el siguiente problema, estas usando una clase `Document` incorrecta**:

```
import javax.swing.text.Document;
```

debes usar la clase Document de iTextPdf:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
```